# I'm trying to solve a 2nd order ODE with frobenius method

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, frobenius-method

I was trying to solve the ODE $$2x(1+x)y'' + (3+x)y' - xy = 0$$ but I couldn't seem to get the recurrence expression. I already got the roots of the indicial equation which are $r=0$ and $r=-1/2$ but after that I'm stuck. Could someone please help me with that, thank you!

Comment: A detailed general description with an example can be found in the [Wiki Frobenius method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method) article. What problem are you having with following it?

Comment: Your roots of the indicia equation are correct.  You should get one power series solution and one solution with $x^{-1/2}$ times a power series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are two indicial solution, I show you how to prodeed for the $r=0$ one, and let you do the one with $r=-\frac 12$.

$\displaystyle-xy=-x\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty}(-a_n)x^{n+1}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}(-a_{n-1})x^n$

- First step is to make $(-x)$ enter the summation.
- Then we shift the index to get a proper $x^n$

$\begin{align}(3+x)y'&=(3+x)\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} na_nx^{n-1}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} (3na_n)x^{n-1}+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} (na_n)x^{n}\\
&=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} (3(n+1)a_{n+1})x^{n}+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} (na_n)x^{n}
\end{align}$

- Here in the first step we split the sum according to powers of $x$ so that the index shifting is facilitated
- Notice the derivation makes the index start at $1$ instead of $0$

$\begin{align}2x(1+x)y''
&=(2x+2x^2)\sum\limits_{i=2}^{\infty} n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}\\
&=\sum\limits_{i=2}^{\infty} (2n(n-1)a_n)x^{n-1}+\sum\limits_{i=2}^{\infty} (2n(n-1)a_n)x^{n}\\
&=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} (2n(n+1)a_{n+1})x^{n}+\sum\limits_{i=2}^{\infty} (2n(n-1)a_n)x^{n}
\end{align}$

- Here the double derivation makes the index start at $2$ instead of $0$

$\begin{align}\text{ODE}
&=\Big(\overbrace{-a_0x}^{y\text{ term}}+\overbrace{3a_1+6a_2x+a_1x}^{y'\text{ term}}+\overbrace{4a_2x}^{y''\text{ term}}\Big)+\\
&\quad\sum\limits_{i=2}^{\infty}\Big(\underbrace{-a_{n-1}}_{y\text{ term}}+\underbrace{3(n+1)a_{n+1}+na_n}_{y'\text{ term}}+\underbrace{2n(n+1)a_{n+1}+2n(n-1)a_n}_{y''\text{ term}}\Big)x^n\end{align}$

- Notice that we have various starting index series $i=0$, $i=1$ and $i=2$, so the common part of all these terms is from $i=2$.
- We isolate all the terms with index $i<2$, i.e the constant terms in $x^0$ and the linear terms in $x^1$.
- We regroup the rest into the same big summation

Now, identification with the zero series gives:

> $\begin{cases}
> 3a_1=0\\
> -a_0+a_1+10a_2=0\\
> (2n+3)(n+1)a_{n+1}+n(2n-1)a_n-a_{n-1}=0
> \end{cases}$

---

For the other one, let set $y(x)=\dfrac{u(x)}{\sqrt{x}}$, the ode is transformed to

$$2x(1+x)u''+(1-x)u'+(1-x)u=0$$

Can you take it from here and apply the same method for the new $(1-x)u'$ and $(1-x)u$ terms ?